# Looking for a HDD tool that can perform deduplication and data compression

Tags: compression, external-hard-drive, deduplication, software-rec

Hi experts and pros! And a happy new year 2011 to everyone!

I'm looking for a "private" tool that could deduplicate my external HDD. I'm sure I have tons of files double on my Disk drives, and I can't afford to do it per hand.
Even better if it can be free, or afordable.

The HDD is file-level access from MAC OS.X and Windows 7 clients only.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm going to move this over to our sister site superuser.com as I think they're more likely to be able to help with this type of question.

Comment: Oh thank you! It was my mistake, I wrote it on the wrong website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX, use MacPorts.

port search duplicate

> duff @0.4 (sysutils)
>       Unix command-line utility for quickly finding duplicates in a given set of files
>   fdupes @1.40 (sysutils)
>       identify and/or delete duplicate files

Comment: I'll check this out. Thanks for the quick reply.